# textArea.setText("") doesn't clear the text in a JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, morse-code

I am trying to clear the text in a JTextArea, and looking at other questions, it seems like calling textArea.setText(""/null) will clear the text area. This does not seem to be happening with my code, and it appends the new text to the text already in the area. Can anyone see something wrong in my code?

```
public class morseJFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private JPanel contentPane;
public JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
public JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                morseJFrame frame = new morseJFrame();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public morseJFrame() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 508);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    textPane.setBounds(5, 5, 424, 194);
    textPane.setText("Enter your alphanumberic text here to translate.");
    contentPane.add(textPane);

    JButton btnTranslate = new JButton("Translate");
    btnTranslate.setBounds(5, 419, 213, 41);
    btnTranslate.addActionListener(this);
    add(btnTranslate);
    contentPane.add(btnTranslate);

    textArea.setBounds(5, 210, 424, 203);
    contentPane.add(textArea);

    JButton btnPlaySound = new JButton("Play Morse Sound");
    btnPlaySound.setBounds(228, 419, 201, 41);
    contentPane.add(btnPlaySound);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String command = e.getActionCommand();
    if (command.equals("Translate")) {
        String text = textPane.getText();
        String translatedText = MorseTranslate.doMorse(text);
        textArea.setText("");
        textArea.setText(translatedText);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What happens if you add a single space instead of nothing?

Comment: Right below `textArea.setText("")` you are setting the text to the text of the `textPane` Object.

Comment: What does `String translatedText = MorseTranslate.doMorse(text);` do?  Because it's this text which you're adding, does it return both the plain and translated text?

Comment: @WyattLowery yes I want to set the text area to that text, but I want the area to be cleared and replaced with new text every time a button is added. Am I doing that incorrectly? Thanks so far for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> This does not seem to be happening with my code, and it appends the new text to the text already in the area

So based on this code...

```
String text = textPane.getText();
String translatedText = MorseTranslate.doMorse(text);
textArea.setText("");
textArea.setText(translatedText);
```

I would suggest that the problem is with your `MorseTranslate.doMorse` which is probably returning the text appended to itself

But, as you can see, this is a matter of "guess work" as we don't have the complete code to go by.

Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: And I get to facepalm again, as I have an ArrayList that I was not clearing in my MorseTranslate class. Thanks everyone for the help. It is working now. And thanks @MadProgrammer for showing me some better question asking techniques. Still trying to get the hang of it hah!

Comment: Nice explanation MadProgrammer

Answer (score 2):

Try to reverse the order like this:

```
   textArea.setText(translatedText);
   textArea.setText("");
```

Use either `textArea.setText(null)` or `textArea.setText("")` are the same thing.

Comment: Hmmm, that just makes it so no text ever appears in the textArea as it gets cleared right away.

Comment: That is clearing it, but now no text is displayed in the box at all because it gets immediately cleared. Right now it is appending to the text already there. I simply want the new message to be displayed.

Comment: *"This does not seem to be happening with my code, and it appends the new text to the text already in the area"*

Answer (score 1):

I think setText() replaces the content (not append), so you don't need to do setText("") and then setText("the text you want"), the latest sentence should be enough.

Comment: Hmmm seems like the message is still only appended and not cleared though.

Comment: *"This does not seem to be happening with my code, and it appends the new text to the text already in the area"*

Answer (score 1):

> `setText("")` doesn't clear the text

Yes it does.

```
textArea.setText("");
```

Here you are clearing the text area.

```
    textArea.setText(translatedText);
```

Here, in the very next line, you are setting it to something else.

Comment: Yes, my problem is that I want to update the text in the textArea, and right now it is being appended. Each time I press the button I want to clear the text and put the new sentence, not add it to what is already there.

Comment: *"This does not seem to be happening with my code, and it appends the new text to the text already in the area"*

Comment: @Eric So you must be appending to `translatedText.`. The methods you're using do not behave as you have described here. The call `setText("")` is redundant.

Comment: @MadProgrammer If you have a point, make it. 'Does not seem to be happening' is hardly conclusive in the face of nearly twenty years of  evidence to the contrary.

Comment: @ejp Given *"... and it appends the new text to the text already in the area"* and the fact that the OP is both calling `setText("")` and `setText(translatedText)`, it would reasonable to assume that the problem is not with `setText`, but with `translatedText`. My point is, like just about every body else, you've misread the question and leaped to the wrong conclusions

Answer (score 0):

You could alternatively try:

```
textArea.setText(null);
```

See if that works. But I agree with Wyatt, you are setting other text right after clearing it.

Comment: *"This does not seem to be happening with my code, and it appends the new text to the text already in the area"*

Answer (score 0):

Have you inserted a simple print statement to see what textPane.getText() is actually setting String text to before sending it to doMorse(String)?